# Are Playstation 4 games locked to a certain region?

Tags: ps4, region-lock

This question has been asked before, but it was for PS3 and Xbox 360 and was asked August 2010. This time around my question goes specifically to PS4, since I'm moving from Mexico to Europe and I was wondering if the European games will run in my console or if I'll have to buy a new one. I never thought of this before (which is why I never paid attention if it was mentioned in reports or specs of the console) and the research I did wasn't too helpful.

Comment: Surprised to see votes to close as "too broad" here. Region-locking isn't a per-game kind of thing, so this question should have a pretty clear-cut definitive answer.

Comment: It was too broad before certain changes made to the inside text as well as the title, yet some people seem to keep voting to close, not sure why since a broader question was asked in 2010 and it wasn't closed.

Comment: Close vote retracted.

Comment: Wolfenstein has been geo-locked due to a german ban of the use of nazi-symbols.

Comment: I think Destiny might be region locked too, Bungie required you to choose between a NA and EU beta key.  To avoid all of this, it might be better to stick with digital editions of games if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, PS4 games will be region-free with 2 major points:

- DLC must match the region of the game you are playing.
- Software makers [still retain the right to region-lock their games](http://m.joystiq.com/2013/06/11/yoshida-ps4-is-region-free/).

Now this is the same as it was with the PS3. Which [according to wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Region-locked_PlayStation_3_games) only had 1 region-locked game: Persona 4 Arena. It is therefore likely that no game makers would region-lock their game.

At this current time, I cannot find any region-locked PS4 games.

Playstation 4 games generally being region free has been confirmed in the "Ultimate PS4 FAQ" on the official Playstation blog for [Europe](http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2013/10/30/playstation-4-the-ultimate-faq/) and [North America](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/30/ps4-the-ultimate-faq-north-america/):

> "In general, neither digital nor disc-based games will be region locked, but PlayStation recommends that all users purchase games at the region of their residence to guarantee the best overall experience and customer service. In certain instances, a software publisher may choose to region lock a game title for specific reasons, but Sony Computer Entertainment expects these instances to be uncommon."

Comment: That's awesome, no need to buy a new console :D

Comment: Do be wary of the DLC tidbit. Your Mexico games would require one psn account, and European games would require another for DLC purposes.

Comment: @Ozmah Note that your store access will still be bound to whatever region your current PSN account is. I'm presuming since you're from Mexico that you have a NA account. You will still only have access to the NA store. If you want to buy from the European store, you'll have to make another account. Also note that games that you buy will have EU DLC codes and Cross-Buy codes will also be EU. I have a NA account and run into this problem as well.

Comment: I was too late to answer, so I just edited in a source from the Playstation blog. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @FAE that is actually something really noteworthy, you're absolutely right, and that is not cool at all. You're right, I have a NA account and the EU DLC you're mentioning is going to be a pain to find a way around that. And since Sony doesn't allow you to change countries for your accounts.

Comment: @Ozmah The way to get around it is to make an EU account that you keep on the same PS3. Your NA account will have access to anything downloaded on the PS3 with the EU account. For example, mine is NA and my boyfriend's account is EU. Our copy of The Last of Us is EU so we have an EU season pass. DLC is downloaded through his account, I log into my account and can then play the DLC. Unfortunately, yes, your purchases well be split across 2 accounts, but there's no other way, as account's can't change region out be multi-region.

Comment: There are games that have region-locked multiplayer, one example being Injustice: Gods Among Us Ultimate Edition. I bought the game as a US version via Amazon, and a friend has the EU version. When either one of us tries to invite the other to a game, the PS says "the application has not been installed" or something like that.